# How can I do with URL add extra Character?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I create a **controller**,contain a method  **Index**.

When I go to website , click the button of  this controller.

Why my URL will extra some Character.

when I delete the extra  Character, it can Successful operation,

but I don't know  how to solve this problem.

I have check _Layout.cshtml . But i didn't find anything woring.
When I click the Link of GatewaySettingDevices.
The URL will go to
http://localhost:10007/**%20**GatewaySettingDevices
What is the  **%20**?

This is my _Layout.cshtml code

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="GatewaySettingClouds" asp-action="Index">GatewaySettingClouds</a>
 </li>
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller=" GatewaySettingDevices" asp-action="Index"> GatewaySettingDevices</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Could you please share your full code snippet?

Comment: To Md Farid Uddin Kiron
I have already Update

Comment: Have a check the answer, it would resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What is the %20***

***`Answer:`*** Its a white space before `" GatewaySettingDevices"`  `controller name`. You have to remove that.

From your code it seems that everything is fine, but the reason for adding extra character on your request is `asp-controller=" GatewaySettingDevices"`

You could see there is a `white sprace` before `" GatewaySettingDevices"` Just get rid of the white space and it should look like below:

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="GatewaySettingClouds" asp-action="Index">GatewaySettingClouds</a>
 </li>
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="GatewaySettingDevices" asp-action="Index"> GatewaySettingDevices</a>
 </li>
```

Hope it would resolve your problem. Let me know if the problem still persists

Comment: You got it !! It is a big help . Thank you~~

Comment: No problem, In programming nothing is stupid, every `;` matters. So no worries